# Illustrator won't export at 300ppi

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, document-setup

Illustrator CC has a wonderful new export window... that doesn't work. You can select different aspects like resolutions, width, height, scale, etc. However even though I have 300ppi selected and my document is setup to be in high res mode, any PNG files I export it always exports at a bit depth of 32 and not 300...

Why is this?

Comment: Bit depth is unrelated to DPI/PPI. The former is how many bits are used to represent colour per pixel and describes how much colour information the file contains (= how accurate and detailed colours are); the latter is the density of dots/pixels per inch when output at 1:1 size and describes the level of detail in the image. The two are completely unrelated.

Comment: How do you see DPI/PPI then on the actual file? I'm trying to upload to a shirt company and I want to scale the image larger but it says the resolution is too low. Even though it should be at 300dpi and very large png

Comment: Open the PNG in Photoshop (assuming you have it), and pull up the Image Size dialogue box (Cmd + Alt + i on a Mac—not sure what the Windows shortcut is). That should show you what the DPI is. If it’s a shirt-printing company, there’s a good chance they accept vector graphics as well. Would uploading a PDF of the artwork not work?

Comment: Do PNGs even store PPI settings?

Comment: There is actually no PPI setting in illustrator, vectors dont have a ppi size. If you want to export for print dont use save for web or save for devices use file export.