# How do I work with an image in Illustrator and save it back as an image?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5

A workflow I frequently encounter is this: I need to take a JPG or PNG image, annotate it with some line art, and save it back as an image.

Photoshop is obviously ideal for this, all things being equal, since PS relates to the object *as* an image.

However, what I want to annotate is very Illustrator-y. I want to use Illustrator in all the ways I'm already familiar with, such as spline curves, assets already in Illustrator, etc.  **But then, I want to save it back out as a JPG or PNG (PNG is fine), with all the art rasterized at native image resolution**.  So if I come in with a 3000x4000 PNG@ 300DPI, I want it to save as a 3000x4000 PNG @ 300 DPI.

**So, I want to either open or place an image in Illustrator, add my Illustrator bits and then save or export an image with the same parameters as the placed image, but with the Illustrator art rasterized onto it.**

Answer (score 4):

Simply link to or embed your raster image, make your annotations, and then use `File > Export` and choose JPG or PNG.

Be aware that many raster formats, such as PNG, don't store any PPI settings. Size is often based upon the total number of pixels, not any density setting (PPI).

See [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/99820/illustrator-wont-export-at-300ppi), [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/120300/confused-about-illustrator-seeming-to-have-a-working-resolution), [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/69667/3270) and [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63085/photoshop-illustrator-indesign-placed-image-different-dimensions-and-resol)

Comment: Thanks Scott, your effort is much appreciated.  Regrettably I must delete the question as it isn't very good apparently, and has attracted downvotes.

Comment: Harper, please do not self-delete questions because they are attracting downvotes. If your question gets downvotes, think about why it would attract downvotes, and edit your question accordingly (in your case, pointless snide remarks about software were probably the cause). You have received an answer which was helpful, but by deleting your question, you are denying the answerer upvotes and thus reputation points, which is the only mechanism we have for rewarding a good answer.